# Why do I have to call spyOn in a beforeEach()?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a simple test suite that has one `it` function inside of it. I want to see if a certain function is called within the function I'm calling, so I have something like this:

```
describe("doStuff", function () {
    var foo = new Foo();
    spyOn(foo, "doOtherStuff");
    foo.doStuff(true);
    it("should do stuff and other stuff", function() {
        expect(foo.stuffDone).toBe(true);
        expect(foo.doOtherStuff).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

However, this gives me the error: `Expected a spy, but got Function.`

After looking around some, I saw all examples had the `spyOn` in a `beforeEach`. So, I changed my test to:

```
describe("doStuff", function () {
    var foo = new Foo();
    beforeEach(function() {
        spyOn(foo, "doOtherStuff");
        foo.doStuff(true);
    });
    it("should do stuff and other stuff", function() {
        expect(foo.stuffDone).toBe(true);
        expect(foo.doOtherStuff).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

And this works. I'm pretty new to jasmine, so I may just be missing something obvious, but I just want to know why it has to be in a `beforeEach` for the `spyOn` to work. It's easy enough to just use the `beforeEach`, but I want to understand better what is going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is simply because Jasmine runs the Specs in a different closure. The `describe` and `it` calls only register callbacks that are added to a queue and then executed by Jasmine later. And Jasmine always cleans up the spies ...

But you can also add the `spyOn` to the `it` callback.