# spyOn: Expected a spy, but got Function

Tags: javascript, jasmine, spyon

I'm creating some Javascript tests using Jasmine framework. I am trying to use the `spyOn()` method to ensure a specific function have been called. here is my code

```
    describe("Match a regular expression", function() {
    var text = "sometext"; //not important text; irrelevant value

    beforeEach(function () {
        spyOn(text, "match");
        IsNumber(text);
    });

    it("should verify that text.match have been called", function () {
        expect(text.match).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

but I'm getting an

> Expected a spy, but got Function

error. I tried to remove the `spyOn(text, "match");` line, and it gave the same error, it seems that the fucntion `spyOn()` is not working is it should.
Any thought?

Comment: spyon is normally used to mock functions. Is 'text' a function here?

Comment: text is a string variable, and match is the function

Comment: Try this thread to get the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13480214/why-do-i-have-to-call-spyon-in-a-beforeeach

Comment: added alternate answer that allows you to use the spyOn method if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that in order to test something like string.match or string.replace, you will not need a spy, but rather to declare text containing what you are matching or replacing and call the function in the beforeEach, then check that the response is equal to what you would expect it to. Here is a simple example:

```
describe('replacement', function(){
    var text;
    beforeEach(function(){
        text = 'Some message with a newline \n or carriage return \r';
        text.replace(/(?:\\[rn])+/g, ' ');
        text.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
    });
    it('should replace instances of \n and \r with spaces', function(){
        expect(text).toEqual('Some message with a newline or carriage return ');
    });
});
```

This will be successful. I would also follow up with a replace to cut down multiple spacing to single spacing, given this scenario. Also, in this case, the `beforeEach` is not necessary as you can use the assignment and call to your function within the `it` statement and before your expectation. It should work similarly with a `string.match` operation if you flip it around to read more like `expect(string.match(/someRegEx/).toBeGreaterThan(0);`.

Hope this helps.

-C§

Edit: Alternatively, you can zip up your `str.replace(/regex/);` or `str.match(/regex/);` into a function that is called and use the `spyOn` there and use `spyOn(class, 'function').and.callthrough();` in your `beforeEach` and use something like `expect(class.function).toHaveBeenCalled();` and `var result = class.function(someString);` (rather than just calling the function) will allow you to test the return value with `expect(class.function(someString)).toEqual(modifiedString);` for a replace or `expect(class.function(someString)).toBeGreaterThan(0);` for the match.

Feel free to +1 if this has given greater insight.

Thanks,

C§

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because its failing on `expect` method. `expect` method is expecting a spy to be passed in but its not. To fix this problem do:

```
var text = new String("sometext");
```

Your test case will still fail because you are not calling the match method anywhere. If you want it to pass, then you would need to call text.match(/WHATEVER REGEX/) inside the `it` function.

Comment: You don't have to call it in beforeEach(), execute it inside `it` function. And what is isNumber function?